# How do you know when to use specific heat for ice or water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, water, ice

> A copper calorimeter can with mass $\rm 0.100 \ kg$ contains $\rm 0.160 \ kg$ of water and $\rm 0.0180 \ kg$ of ice in thermal equilibrium at atmospheric pressure. If $\rm 0.750 \ kg$ of lead at $\rm  255°C$ is dropped into the calorimeter can, what is the final temperature? Assume that no heat is lost to the surroundings?

My thought process of how I do the ice melting part :

$\rm Q_{ice} + Q_{melt} + Q_{liquid}$

so, it is :

$\rm  0.018(2100)T+0.16(4190)T+0.018(334×10^3)$

But on chegg they didn't use $2100$ but they just use $4190$ instead and I am confused on why they did that.

Like I know it because ice melting into water but how come this problem they don't even use it?

> In a container of negligible mass, $\rm 0.200 kg$ of ice at an initial
> temperature of $\rm -40.0°C$ is mixed with a mass $m$ of water that has an
> initial temperature of $\rm 80.0°C$. No heat is lost to the surroundings. If the
> final temperature of the system is $\rm 28.0°C$ , what is the mass $m$ of the
> water that was initially at $\rm 80.0°C$?

For this problem they did :

$0.2(2100)(40)+0.2(334×10^3)+0.2(4190)(80)$.

If that was the case earlier then wouldn't you substitute $2100$ for $4190$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ice doesn't change temperature in your first example, so its specific heat is not relevant. (If it's at equilibrium with liquid water, it must be at 0°C—exposed to heating, all it can do is melt to produce more liquid water, which has a different specific heat.)

Comment: ahh thank you so much i can kinda see it now. But for clarification how do you know the ice is not changing the temperature.

Comment: Common sense precludes the possibility of it cooling down from encountering the hot lead. It cannot heat up, as it would no longer be ice.

Comment: wait now im confused didn't you say earlier that the ice melt so it is heating up

Comment: To be more precise, the ice does not undergo [sensible heating](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_heat) while it is ice.